# how to attach product ID with Product Image

Tags: product, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, template, products-management

I want to add 'ID' attribute with product_id value.

My code  is

```
$_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();   
$count_image = count($_images);
$i = 1; 

foreach($_images as $_image){

        if($_image->getDisabled()==1){
            $imageData = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(80,95);
            $content_images .= "<li class=\"thbnileimg\"><img height=\"80\" width=\"95\" src=\"$imageData\" alt=\"Rim\" onclick=\"SetRim('$imageData')\" />";
            break;
        }
        else {
            if($i==$count_image){
                $imageData = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(80,95);
                $content_images .= "<li class=\"thbnileimg\"><img height=\"80\" width=\"95\" src=\"$imageData\" alt=\"Rim\" onclick=\"SetRim('$imageData')\" />";

                }
        }
         $i++;

        }
    }
```

**How can I add Product ID as ID in Image tag in LI**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add an id to the li tag that is fairly simple but be aware that the [id attribute should be unique on the page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). *NOTE: If you just had product id in the id it will cause issues when you have more than one image on the page.*

I would suggest adding image id and product id, which should be unique. The code would be as follows.

```
$liId = $product->getId().'-'.$image->getId();
$content_images .= "<li id=\"$liId\" class=\"thbnileimg\"><img height=\"80\" width=\"95\" src=\"$imageData\" alt=\"Rim\" onclick=\"SetRim('$imageData')\" />";
```